# Doubt about property of hermitian operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, definition

For any hermitian operator M, prove that
\begin{equation}
\langle Ma|b \rangle = \langle a|Mb \rangle
\end{equation}

My attempt:
Let
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle a| = \sum_i a_i^*\langle i|\\
|b\rangle = \sum_j b_j|j\rangle
\end{eqnarray}
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle Ma| &=& \sum_{i} a_i^*M\langle i|\\
\therefore\langle Ma|b\rangle &=& \sum_{i,j} a_i^*b_jM\langle i|j\rangle\\
&=& \sum_{i,j} a_i^*b_jM\delta_{ij}\\
&=&\sum_{i} a_i^*b_iM
\end{eqnarray}
Now similarly,
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle a|Mb\rangle &=& \sum_{i,j} a_i^*b_j\langle i|M|j \rangle\\
&=& \sum_{i,j} a_i^*b_j M_{ij}
\end{eqnarray}
I don't know what to do next. I feel that I am very close to the answer

Comment: How exactly are you defining a Hermitian operator?

Comment: @BySymmetry I have not used the hermiticity of the operator but the theorem does mention operator M being hermitian.

Comment: So my issue is that the statement you are trying to prove is what is normally taken as the definition of a Hermitian operator, so in order to prove this you must be using some other definition. Using an alternative equivalent definition is fine, but we need to know what it is in order to help you here

Comment: @BySymmetry I am using the definition that if M is hermitian, then $M$ = $M^\dagger$

Comment: And how are you defining the $\dagger$ operation?

Comment: @BySymmetry $\dagger$ is taking transpose and complex conjugate of the operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, The identity that you are trying to prove is mainly taken as the definition of a Hermitian operator.

A is Hermitian if $A=A^\dagger$ or equivalently if $\langle x,Ay\rangle =\langle Ax,y\rangle \ \ \forall\ \ x,y.$

This can be seen as follows:
$$\langle a|A^\dagger|b\rangle \equiv \langle b|A|a\rangle ^*$$
At this point, We can proceed in two equivalent way
$$\langle a|A^\dagger |b\rangle=\langle b|aA\rangle^*=\langle Aa|b\rangle$$
Or
$$\langle a|A^\dagger|b\rangle =\langle Ab|a\rangle^*=\langle a|bA\rangle $$
Hence$$\langle a|bA\rangle =\langle Aa|b\rangle $$